# Are Assemblers Installed By Default?

Tags: assembly, arm, raspberry-pi

Hello awesome community!

I am just starting with learning Assembly Language. I am going to start with ARM Assembly on my Raspberry Pi B+, and later in want to learn Assembly for 64 bit Intel processors running Windows (8.1).

But i was wondering if the assembler for the ARM processor is installed by default with the Raspbian OS distro. I was also wondering about this for Windows 8.1.

In case they are not installed, where can i find an assembler for my Rapsberry Pi B+ and my Windows 8.1 computer with a 64 bit Intel processor?

Bonus Question:
I found a PDF explaining the basics of ARM Assembly for the ARM v3 architecture.
Now, what ARM version does the Raspberry Pi B+ use and, does it matter in case the Raspberry Pi uses another version?

Comment: Your RaspberryPi OS will come with an assembler, Windows won't. Asking   where to find off-site resources is off-topic here.

Comment: You know I just got a windows 8.1 machine and something had installed visual c++ ont it, not sure if it was a side effect of something else I installed (did not set it up as a development machine).  I actually went to the uninstall software dialog and saw the visual C in there, but didnt mess with it.

Comment: In general no, neither linux nor mac nor windows should you expect to have a native compiler nor assembler.  Much less should you expect to find a cross compiler for a non-native platform come with any operating system.  Now saying that a number of linux distros will have a native toolchain by default in the install but not cross compilers (including assemblers in these generic categories).

Comment: yeah, the armv3 is interesting and there is a lot that matches armv4 and beyond but armv4 is where you should start, infocenter.arm.com has the docs you need look at the archtectural reference manuals.  The raspberry pi b uses an armv6 I think and the new pi2 an armv7 if I remember right, but that is all documented on many many web pages the rpi pages themselves or wikipedia, etc.  For the most part you can use armv4 everywhere (not talking cortex-m) or the same or lower as the architecture you have but armv3 and below does not cross over to armv4

Comment: binutils is what you are after and you can get cross toolchains in many places limiting to binutils and not a c compiler or other high level language makes the choices bigger.  dev kit arm, yagarto, the launchpad one, mbed's web thing might work, or just build from sources, pretty easy for just binutils and not a compiler.  as well as all the pay-for ones.  google is your friend so are the raspberry pi forums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

raspberry pi B+ uses ARMv6. GCC is installed on the raspberry pi and can be used to assemble ARM assembly or you can use the GNU assembler `as`, when using gcc the default staring label will be `main` but most other assemblers will use `_start`. It will be easier to use GCC because it can use C functions such as `printf`.

when compiling with gcc it will produce an executable, but with `as` it will output object code which needs to be linked.

here is a simple hello world program

```
.text
.global _start
_start:
    mov r0, #1        @// write to stdout
    ldr r1, =message  @// memory address of message
    ldr r2, =len      @// length of message
    mov r7, #4        @// Linux system call SYS_WRITE
    swi 0             @// call software interupt

    mov r0, #0
    mov r7, #1        @// exit
    swi 0

.data
message:
    .ascii "hello world\n"
len = .-message
```

compile with using gcc

```
gcc -nostdlib hello.s -o hello
```

or

```
as hello.s -o hello.o
ld hello.o -o hello
```